# How can the landscape screen orientation be restricted in android?

Tags: android

How can the landscape screen orientation be restricted in android?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question is very short, but I believe you are asking how to restrict an Activity's display to a specific orientation. To do so try using the `android:screenOrientation` in the `<Activity>` tag(s) in your Manifest file.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Comment: @mbaird Is there a way to do it from inside an activity? Say I want the user not to be able to change the screen configuration if some event occurs.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the Activity parameters as defined below..

```
<activity android:allowTaskReparenting=["true" | "false"]
          android:alwaysRetainTaskState=["true" | "false"]
          android:clearTaskOnLaunch=["true" | "false"]
          android:configChanges=["mcc", "mnc", "locale",
                                 "touchscreen", "keyboard", "keyboardHidden",
                                 "navigation", "orientation", "fontScale"]
          android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
          android:excludeFromRecents=["true" | "false"]
          android:exported=["true" | "false"]
          android:finishOnTaskLaunch=["true" | "false"]
          android:icon="drawable resource"
          android:label="string resource"
          android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" |
                              "singleTask" | "singleInstance"]
          android:multiprocess=["true" | "false"]
          android:name="string"
          android:noHistory=["true" | "false"]  
          android:permission="string"
          android:process="string"
          android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "user" | "behind" |
                                     "landscape" | "portrait" |
                                     "sensor" | "nosensor"]
          android:stateNotNeeded=["true" | "false"]
          android:taskAffinity="string"
          android:theme="resource or theme"
          android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
                                       "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                                       "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                                       "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
                                       "adjustResize", "adjustPan"] >   
    . . .
</activity>
```

Comment: great dude... it really rocks.