# How to make an application fixes oriented in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to make my android application fixed oriented, where no one can change the app's orientation by any kind of force. So far I used these in my manifest's activity tag:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

it's working fine in my emulator, but in real device when I press the orientation change button it's orientation is changing and getting a force close. What should I do next?

Comment: Try this link........
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320373/how-can-the-landscape-screen-orientation-be-restricted-in-android

Comment: If this helps please 1 up my comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define **android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"**
 in your manifest then the activity won't restart but instead **onConfigurationChanged** will be called.

So override onConfigurationChanged method in your java file.

Answer (score 1):

this put in mainfest

```
<activity
            android:name=".Assign"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```